# Strategy to maximize the expected sum of $3$ numbers each drawn from $\sim U(0, 1)$

Tags: probability, expected-value

Consider a uniform random number generator $\sim U(0, 1)$.

We can generate a maximum of $10$ numbers sequentially. We are only allowed to keep $3$ numbers at a time. If we currently have $3$ numbers, then we cannot draw the next number until we discard $1$ of our current numbers.

What is the optimal strategy to maximize the expectation of the sum of the $3$ numbers we have in the end? What is the expectation of the sum of the $3$ numbers?

I think I know how to solve this problem for the case where we are allowed to keep one number. I would work backwards and start at the $10$th draw, which has expectation $0.5$. If the $9$-th draw is $\leq 0.5$, I will discard it and proceed with the $10$th draw. Then I can compute the expectation of a $9$th draw, which would come out to be $0.5 \cdot 0.75 + 0.5 \cdot 0.5 = 0.625 $. And then I can repeat this process all the way to the beginning, and I should see this number increase monotonically. We will also see our threshold of deciding to draw again or not will decrease monotonically for each subsequent draw, i.e., on the first draw, we are much more likely to be more daring than, say, on the $9$th draw. I don't know if there's an easy way to come up with a generic formula for this (feel free to let me know if there is) since it can become tedious to recurse all the way back to the first draw.

So the above is how I would approach the problem if we were allowed to keep $1$ number. I don't know how to generalize this approach to being allowed to keep more than $1$ number. It is obvious to me that we should at least draw $3$ numbers, and we should never have less than $3$ numbers on hand. It's also clear that we should never discard more than $1$ number. With this information, it is still not clear to me how to approach this problem.

Comment: Your approach would work: Work from the end to find the expected final sum at the $k$th draw. If the current sum is less than that, discard the lowest number. I think what could also work is considering the expectation of the maximum of the remaining numbers (which would be $\frac{k}{k+1}$, where $k$ is the number of remaining draws). If this is greater than the lowest number that you currently have, discard that number.

Comment: @VarunVejalla Do you mean my approach for keeping 1 number can be generalized to keeping 3 numbers?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, there would have to be some small modifications.

Comment: @VarunVejalla I see. It's still not obvious to me how this will work. Can you show an example of what the expected "final sum" at the k-th draw looks like?

Comment: Expectation of the 10th draw is $0.5$ as you write. So if one of your numbers is less than $0.5$ after 9 tries, you draw on the 10th time. What happens at 9th draw?

Comment: @gt6989b Consider we have 3 numbers, x,y,z, on hand, such that $x < y < z$. Then I would discard the $x$ if $x \leq 0.5$ and decide to make a 10th draw? If $x > 0.5$, I will forgo the 10th draw?

Comment: Yes, that looks correct. The expected value from discarding and drawing would be $1/2 + y + z$ versus $x+y+z$.

Comment: @student010101 great, this is correct. Now how do you figure out the strategy the turn before that?

Comment: @gt6989b It seems I would just employ the same strategy as the case with 1 number. So I need to compute the expectation of conducting a 9-th draw, which would be $0.5 * (0.5 + y + z) + 0.5*(x + y + z)$. Let's say this evaluates to $s_8$. If our smallest number after 8 draws is $\leq s_8$, then we will conduct a 9-th draw?

Comment: @student010101 i think so, yes

Comment: @gt6989b Is there an easy way to get a closed form solution? even for the 1 number case, it does not seem it would have been easy to back out a closed form solution. Perhaps there is some induction that could be drawn if I enumerate a few more examples for the 1 number case, but for this case, it seems much more difficult.

Comment: my guess is as good as yours :) I don't know, I am sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach for keeping a single number works here as well.  In the single number case, at each round you have a threshold that says you should stand pat if your number is above that.  For the three number case, the threshold stays the same and you compare your smallest number with the threshold.

Imagine a less favorable game where my adversary can force me to pick two numbers that can not be discarded.  I pick the two highest.  Once the adversary does that, I am back to the one number game and should follow its strategy.  Your game has an advantage to me that if the new number is very high I have the option to discard one of the numbers I would have fixed.  The critical observation is that the threshold is decreasing. If I would not discard the lowest number this round, I would not discard it in any later round either.  If I would discard the lowest number this round, it is just like playing the more restrictive game.

On average, you will stand pat later in the three number game because all the numbers have to be above the threshold.  The strategy does not change.  Look at the threshold for the one number game.  If the lowest number is below that, throw it away and draw again.

The threshold with $n$ games to play is $\frac {a(n)}{2^{2^n-1}}$ where $a(n)$ is given in OEIS [A167424](http://oeis.org/A167424), which starts $1, 5, 89, 24305, 1664474849, 7382162541380960705, 139566915517602820239076685726696149889$

Comment: I think it's making more and more sense that the threshhold stays the same. The expected value of the smallest number is the same as the expected value of the single number game right? How do I compute the expected value of the middle and maximum number?

Comment: No, the expected value of the smallest is not the same as the single number game because it starts out (on average) smaller.  It is then more likely that you discard it.  I don't think there is an easy way except following the tree.

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. Also, what do you mean by "tree" here? A decision tree?

Comment: Yes, following the decision tree, computing the expected value at each stage.

Comment: I was trying to see if I could derive a closed form expression. After the first draws, I can obtain analytical expressions for the expected value of the smallest,  middle, and largest value using order statistics, but after that, it seems I can't come up with an analytical solution of any sort. I tried some stuff, but nothing turning out nicely.